# StringBuilder's toString function with Java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, functional-java

Have a `String` that I convert to `IntStream`, sort it and get a `StringBuilder` back. Upon calling `toString` on it, I am seeing the concatenated ASCII values vs the sorted
characters in string format. Why is that? What is the fix?

```java
class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "zwdacb";
        StringBuilder sb = s.chars()
            .sorted()
            .collect(() -> new StringBuilder(),
                (x, y) -> x.append(y), 
                (StringBuilder sb1, StringBuilder sb2) -> 
                    sb1.append(sb2));

        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Output
`979899100119122`

Comment: What is your expectation? As you say, you convert the string to and `IntStream` so you have only the ascii values

Comment: Use `StringBuilder sb = s.codePoints() .sorted() .collect(() -> new StringBuilder(), (x, y) -> x.appendCodePoint(y),  (StringBuilder sb1, StringBuilder sb2) -> sb1.append(sb2));` which can be simplified to `StringBuilder sb = s.codePoints() .sorted() .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint,  StringBuilder::append);` You can also simplify the printing, `System.out.println(sb);`. Or without streams: `char[] chars = "zwdacb".toCharArray(); Arrays.sort(chars); System.out.println(chars);`

Answer (score 2):

The output you are seeing is the result of concatenating the ASCII values of the characters in the sorted order, rather than the characters themselves. This happens because the `sorted()` method returns an `IntStream` of the character values (ASCII values), and when you collect these values into a `StringBuilder`, they are treated as integer values.

Try with this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "zwdacb";
    String sortedString = s.chars()
            .sorted()
            .collect(StringBuilder::new, (sb, c) -> sb.append((char) c), StringBuilder::append)
            .toString();
    System.out.println(sortedString);
}
```

Comment: Actually, it's `String.chars()` that returns an `IntStream`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Initially it is `String.chars()` that returns `IntStream`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the plain-old approach instead of streams. It's more concise in this particular case:

```java
var initialString = "zwdacb";
var chars = initialString.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(chars);
var sortedString = new String(chars);
```